# Publisher logo metadata with no img

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

For the article rich result, Google gives that Microdata example:

```html
<div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="https://www.schema.org/Organization">
<div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://www.schema.org/ImageObject">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/logo.jpg"/>
  <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.google.com/logo.jpg">
  <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
  <meta itemprop="height" content="60">
</div>
```

For design reasons, I do not want to show the logo (or at least not in that place).

If I give no information about any `img`, the Google Testing Tool gives an error. But if I delete the `img` tag but keep the meta information about the `img`, the testing tool is ok.

Can I omit the `img` tag, but keep the rest? I mean, I would give Google the metadata information of the image but I would not show the logo of the publisher to the user/public of the web. Like that:

```html
<div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="https://www.schema.org/Organization">
<div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://www.schema.org/ImageObject">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.google.com/logo.jpg">
  <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
  <meta itemprop="height" content="60">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the article rich result, Google uses the logo only for AMP pages. The [logo guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles#logo-guidelines) don’t say anything about whether the logo has to be displayed on the page.

Providing the URL of the logo (without using the `img` element) is perfectly fine from the perspectives of Schema.org and Microdata.

But note that Google’s example is invalid HTML+Microdata. If the value is a URL, you have to use `link` instead of `meta`:

```html
<div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://www.schema.org/ImageObject">
  <link itemprop="url" href="/logo.jpg">
  <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
  <meta itemprop="height" content="60">
</div>
```